# Error while building the project- cannot resolve method placeholder()

Tags: android

```
package com.example.shivamgoyal.photografia;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mImagesList;
    private Context mContext;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageList) {
        mContext = context;
        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
        mImagesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.mImagesList = imageList;

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<mImagesList.size();i++) {
            if(mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                mTempArry.add(mImagesList.get(i));
            }
        }

        return mTempArry;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }
    };


    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_multiphoto_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }


    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String imageUrl = mImagesList.get(position);

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load("file://"+imageUrl)
                .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
    }


    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImagesList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public CheckBox checkBox;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        }
    }

}
```

Using android studio 3.0 canary 6 on Windows. When the build process is running there is error- cannot resolve method placeholder() , using glide 3.5.2 but still getting this error. There is error only in placeholder() method, suggest some solutions to get rid from this problem.Imported glide files but it doesn't resolve.

Comment: What is the version of Glide?

Comment: #Shivam Facing same problem yet ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes

Comment: @AshutoshSagar 3.7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your **[GLIDE](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)** version .

**`Placeholder`** can be added before the loading the media . You should use below version .

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

**FYI**.

> Glide ships with a standard **[placeholder](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-placeholders-fade-animations)** , which is (for the version
>   3.6.1) active by default .

Comment: should i download .jar file for version 3.6.1 or i just add the statement in gradle file

Comment: @shivamgoyal `gradle`

Comment: @shivamgoyal Solved this yet ?

Comment: there is only one error cannot resolve method .placeholder(int), and i am using glide 3.7.0.   please help

Comment: @shivamgoyal wait

Comment: @shivamgoyal here working . for test case, remove `apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())`

Comment: completely remove it or add .centerCrop()

Comment: one doubt of other topic: initially i was using several linear layouts to design the application but now i have changed my linear layouts to relative layout then what type of changes should i do in my java code?